Why is the implemented CPFP carve-out limited to 10 kvB, when originally 1 kvB was proposed as the limit?
Does anyone have some background on the decision process that led to the CPFP carve-out transaction being limited to 10,000 vB, when the original proposal suggested a limit of 1000 vB?
